# No `render` method found on the returned component instance: you may have forgotten to define `render`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router-dom

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

interface PrivateRoute {
  isLoggedIn: boolean;
  path: string;
  component: any;
  exact: boolean;
}

const PrivateRoute: React.FC<PrivateRoute> = ({
  isLoggedIn,
  component,
  ...rest
}) => {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      component={(props: any) =>
        isLoggedIn ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/" />
      }
    />
  );
};
const mapStateToProps = (state: any) => ({
  isLoggedIn: !!state.auth.uid,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PrivateRoute);
```

So this is the component I have, for creating private routes. And the router is this;

```
import HeaderTop from "./HeaderTop/HeaderTop";
import HeaderBottom from "./HeaderBottom/HeaderBottom";
import Body from "./Body/Body";
import Footer from "./Footer/Footer";
import Movies from "./ShowPages/Movies";
import Series from "./ShowPages/Series";
import NotFoundPage from "./NotFoundPage/NotFoundPage";
import { Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import LoginPage from "./LoginPage/LoginPage";
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";
import PrivateRoute from "./PrivateRoute";
export const history = createBrowserHistory();

const HomePage: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <Router history={history}>
      <div>
        <HeaderTop />
        <HeaderBottom />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" component={LoginPage} exact={true} />
          <PrivateRoute path="/meerkast" component={Body} exact={true} />
          <PrivateRoute path="/movies" component={Movies} exact={true} />
          <PrivateRoute path="/series" component={Series} exact={true} />
          <Route component={NotFoundPage} />
        </Switch>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default HomePage;
```

So what is going on here? I don't have class component why would I have render method anywhere? I found this question is asked many times on stackoverflow but no one had the proper answer.

Comment: I have to play with this to see why it’s going wrong, but I would recommend using useSelector inside of PrivateRoute rather than using connect.  Does that fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is with inconsistant casing on the `component` prop.  Your `PrivateRoute` gets a prop `component` with a lowercase `c`.  When you call `<Component {...props} />` with an uppercase `C`, that `Component` variable doesn't exist.

I understand the reason that you used uppercase in the JSX, which is that React interprets lowercase names as built-in elements.  I also understand the reason that you used lowercase in the `PrivateRoute` props, which is that you wanted to be be consistent with react-router-dom's `Route` props.

But we have to make the two coexist.  We do this by renaming the lowercase `component` to `Component` in the spread expression.

```
const PrivateRoute: React.FC<PrivateRoute> = ({
  isLoggedIn,
  component: Component,
  ...rest
}) => {
```